# How to add a parameter in strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How to add a parameter in strong params?

I can choose the "type" when the object is instantiated.
But I can't update this "type".

Can I do two methods with parameters.
for example:

```
def custom_field_params
  params.require(:custom_field).permit(:name, :required, :type_id, options_attributes: [:id, :name, :position, :_destroy])
end

def update_custom_field_params
  params.require(:custom_field).permit(:name, :required, options_attributes: [:id, :name, :position, :_destroy])
end
```

Can I combine these two methods into one method?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `custom_field_params` as is, and in your `update` method, do something like:

`MyModel.update(custom_field_params.select { |k, _v| k != :type_id })`